# Pushing change to multiple forks

Tags: git

I have a multiple forks of a program with minor changes to customize the program for each specific client. I have the original program set as a remote for all of the forks.

When I fix a bug in the original program I would like to push the change to all of the forks without destroying their customizations.
Currently when I try to push the change to a fork I get an error asking me to pull the latest changes, but this overwrites the customizations made in the forked version.

Is it possible to do what I'm describing with Git, or am I fundamentally misusing this tool? Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to do what I'm describing with Git,

No.

> am I fundamentally misusing this tool?

Well, not fundamentally, but misusing, yes.

The right way is the following: you store all customizations in separate branches. Every time you update the main branch (`master`, most certainly) you rebase all customized branches on top of the main branch and then push all branches.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I was hoping of avoid that way since it takes time to set up, but it makes a lot of sense now that I've tried doing things my way and failed.  Thank you for your time.